# PATCH request using HttpURLConnection in JAVA

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

How to execute PATCH request of RESTHeart API using HttpURLConnection in JAVA .Its giving back 405 as status.

```
public class TestRestHeartUpdate{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

URL url;
url = new 
URL("http://127.0.0.1:8080/testDB1/col1/5967c13e61f73b88018db783");

HttpURLConnection hc;
hc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
hc.setDoInput(true);
hc.setDoOutput(true);
hc.setRequestMethod("POST");
hc.setRequestProperty("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "PATCH");

hc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/hal+json");
hc.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/hal+json");
hc.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
hc.setRequestProperty("If-Match","5967c28f42483b1c3dbedc54");
hc.setUseCaches(false);
hc.connect();

byte[] opB = " {'rating':'VeryGood'}".getBytes("UTF-8");
OutputStream os = hc.getOutputStream();
os.write(opB);
System.out.println(hc.getResponseCode());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Http code 405 means method not allowed. This indicates that your web server is not allowing PATCH requests and that you'll need to configure it to accept PATCH method type.

Comment: can you please tell me how to configure the server to accept PATCH method type